# What is the syntax for Application_ItemSend()?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a subroutine called Read in Outlook. I want to execute it every time I send an email.

I tried to call it as part of `Application_ItemSend()`, but it does nothing.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend() 'calls the first function when you send a mail
Read
End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Application_ItemSend never gets called?Or that Read() function does not work? In the latter case you really need to post its source.

Comment: See my answer below, is that what you ware trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Should be*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Call Read
End Sub

Public Sub Read()
        Debug.Print "success"
End Sub
```

***[Calling Sub and Function procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures)***